# grocerycrud add_action not showing correct URL

Tags: php, grocery-crud

I am trying to add an action in an old system using GroceryCRUD 1.3.1, using the following line of code:

```
$crud->add_action('Note', base_url('assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/css/images/note.png'), base_url('meta/organisation_admin/manage_user_notes'), '', array($this, 'get_pk'));
```

The action button is created, but the URL is not correct. Instead of the URL specified, I get this (for example):

```
meta/organisation_admin/12345
```

Where 12345 is the user's ID, so my get_pk function does return the correct primary key, but the URL is not right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well i will recommend you upgrade the GC library. It have evolved way ahead and might be - your issue what you are facing in might also get resolved. If you still are having issue post upgradation, do share your concerns, will look in for a proper solution / workaround for the issue.

Comment: Other add_action() calls are working fine. They are identical as far as I can see, except for the parts that NEED to be different. Upgrading is a decent suggestion, but not sure that this is a bug in GC, as a bug of this caliber would've broken many systems. It's gotta be something I am doing wrong. I will attempt an upgrade, but not sure whether the previous developer customized anything - always scared of that :-) Backups, I guess.

Comment: well, i have been around with GC for years now.. if i remember - nearly 5 yrs.. and i have upgraded .. i have not faced much issues at all - also have customized. So far, as my experience goes in .. yes it is true the library have had some bugs, but never heard of this one. You can find me back even in their forum - quite active there then here. :) Feel free to get back in touch in forum if required.